# MacOS terminal: Can not access folders with @ in path

Tags: macos, terminal

I am facing a strange behavior on my MacOs terminal.

When I try to autocomplete a folder which has an @-sign included all my /etc/hosts entries are shown...

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/php@
```

an then pressing tap shows

```
@::1                               @localhost.                        @custom-etc-host-entry.domain
```

I can reproduce this for my user and for root.

Maybe some can help me to find the root cause of this.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the `@` with `\` in your path:

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/php\@
```

Then pressing tab will show something like this:

```
php@5.6/ php@7.2/
```